# protobuf MessageToJson removes fields with value 0

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers, enumeration

I'm writing a Python script that receives protobufs, converts them to json objects, and pushes them to another service. I use `json.loads(MessageToJson(protobuf))` to convert the protobuf to a python dictionary object. Later I convert it back to json with `json.dumps(dictionary)`.

I have a proto with an optional enumerated field such as:

```
enum C_TYPE
{
    AB = 0;
    BC = 1;
    CD = 2;
}
```

When I receive a proto with a field designated as `BC` everything works as I expect it. When I receive a proto with a field designated `AB` that field gets ignored -- it does not turn up in the python dictionary or subsequent json dump. A workaround I have found is to use `json.loads(MessageToJson(protobuf, including_default_value_fields=True))` but that will create default values for all missing fields, not just the ones that have a `0` enumeration. It implies that the field with enumeration `0` is missing - but it's not!

What is the correct way to retrieve the value of the enumeration field when it is set to `0`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no correct way, I'm defining my protobufs incorrectly. For enumerated fields, the first value *is* the default value. This means if a protobuf comes through without a set value, it is set to the default value and, when converted to json, ignored (unless you want to keep all default values.)

Thus, it is recommended use throw-away names for the default value to be able to properly distinguish when it has been set. i.e. I should define my protobuf as:

```
enum C_TYPE
{
    NONE = 0;
    AB = 1;
    BC = 2;
    CD = 3;
}
```

From [Protobuf Documentation on Optional Fields And Default Values](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#optional):

> For enums, the default value is the first value listed in the enum's
>   type definition. This means care must be taken when adding a value to
>   the beginning of an enum value list.

Additionally from an [issue on golang/protobuf](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/258):

> This is working as intended. proto3 zero-values are omitted in the
>   JSON format too. The zero-value should be a "throwaway" value: it's
>   also what you will see if the sender of a serialized message sets the
>   field to an invalid or unrecognized value.

Answer (score 4):

In protobuf in C++ it is possible to add an option to always print primitive fields.
Adding this option in the MessageToJson conversion makes protobuf add the parameters even though they are set to zero.

```
google::protobuf::util::JsonPrintOptions options;
options.always_print_primitive_fields = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you may set `including_default_value_fields` argument to True to get the value of all fields.